# Handling a NullReference exception in Function

Tags: vb.net

I wrote the function below. However, when handling the status variable, I get an error NullReference Exception unhandled by user code.

I come from VBA where I did not have to deal with this type of issue on my functions. the status variable is supposed to set my objects properties to true or false.

I tried setting

```
status = New Boolean
status = False
```

But nothing worked

Here is my code

```
    Option Strict On
    Option Explicit On

    Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
    Imports System.Windows.Forms

    Module sheetView

    Function viewSheets(sheetName As String, status As Boolean) As String

        Dim ThisApplication As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application()
        Dim WB As Excel._Workbook
        Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet


        WB = CType(Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveWorkbook, Excel.Workbook)
        WS = CType(WB.Sheets(sheetName), Excel.Worksheet)

        With ThisApplication

            .ScreenUpdating = False

            WS.Select()

            .ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = status
            .ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = status
            .ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = status
            .DisplayFormulaBar = status
            .DisplayStatusBar = status
            .ExecuteExcel4Macro("Show.ToolBar(""Ribbon"", status)")


            .ScreenUpdating = True


        End With

        Return ""

    End Function

    End Module


    Private Sub btnEmployeeDashboard_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEmployeeDashboard.Click

    sheetView.viewSheets("employeeBoard", True)

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `status` variable is where the problem is? Do you know on which line the error is happening? Is there a reason you are declaring `WB` as a `_Workbook` but casting `Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveWorkbook` to a `Workbook` (no underscore)?

Comment: The status variable is assigning to a null reference, so @JLRishe is right, hard to say where its failing without stepping through a debugger, can you post the stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `NullReference` occurs when you try to access a class member when there is no object instance.

In other words: one of the values (`ThisApplication`/ `WB` / `WS` / `WS.ActiveWindow`) is empty. Step through your code in the debugger to find out which one.